# Running Totals in a VIEW

Tags: mysql, view, cumulative-sum

I have a mySql table called `ClosedOrdersTbl` with 2 columns in it: `ID` and `NetProfit`.

I would like to create a VIEW with a running totals of the column `NetProfit`... Like the example below:

```
ID      NetProfit       RunningTotal  
1          100              100  
2           50              150  
3          200              350
```

I have tried the following code:

```
SELECT ID, NetProfit,
       @RTl := @RT1 + NetProfit AS RunningTotal
   FROM ClosedOrdersTbl
   ORDER BY ID;
```

But i don't think a VIEW will accept variables?

So if anyone would be so nice to guide me in the right direction i would be very thankfull:-)

Comment: Which MySql/MariaDB version are you using?

Comment: Hi Tbuc - I'm running mysql v5.7.28-31